# TypeScript compile error when using express with the http module

Tags: typescript

TypeScript server-side code:

```
import * as express from 'express';
import * as http from 'http';
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
```

Runs into this error when running `tsc`:

```
express Argument of type 'Application' is not assignable to parameter of type
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a now-patched [bug](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/10507) in the typings file. To work around this, you will need to install express off of the GitHub commit.

```
typings install github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/express-serve-static-core/express-serve-static-core.d.ts#58bf29ff6e6d7031bb7ec463732625bb2a0001d0 --global --save
```

Install the other dependencies of express in the normal way using `typings search` and `typings install`. Make sure to use the `--global` flag on each dependency, and to install off dt instead of npm. At the end, your typings.json will look something like this:

```
{
  "dependencies": {},
  "globalDependencies": {
    "express": "registry:dt/express#4.0.0+20160708185218",
    "express-serve-static-core": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/express-serve-static-core/express-serve-static-core.d.ts#58bf29ff6e6d7031bb7ec463732625bb2a0001d0",
    "mime": "registry:dt/mime#0.0.0+20160316155526",
    "node": "registry:env/node#6.0.0+20160918225031",
    "serve-static": "registry:dt/serve-static#0.0.0+20160606155157",
  }
}
```